# Phantomjs error while running tests in angular cli

Tags: phantomjs, angular-cli, polyfills

I am trying to run ng test in Angular Cli project using phantom browser and I am getting below error. I googled it and realized that it has something to do with polyfill (Backward compatibility?). I want to understand what's wrong here and how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

**PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(_a = ((Object))).assign.apply')
  at webpack:///~/@angular/common/src/pipes/intl.js:187:0 <- src/test.ts:34449**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to uncomment those from your polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
```

Comment: PhantomJS support for es6 is still a work in progress, that why you need to use polyFills in order to make it work in phantomJS browser .

Comment: I guess `es6` won't happend with `PhantomJS` due to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE